# MySQL DEFINER specification

Tags: mysql

Which document specifies the MySQL `definer` format?

Specifically, what does `%` mean (and why exactly this sign is used) in `definer admin@%`?

Answer (score 0):

The format used by MySQL here is defined in [the MySQL documentation for `CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html), among other places:

> If a **user** value is given for the `DEFINER` clause, it should be a MySQL account specified as `'user_name'@'host_name'` (the same format used in the [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) statement), [`CURRENT_USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user), or [`CURRENT_USER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user).

MySQL users can have a host name of `%`, allowing them to connect from any hostname.